# Using a referenced project's TargetPath in a post-build task

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, projects-and-solutions, post-build-event, visual-studio-macros

Using Visual Studio 2010, I need to have a C# project run a post-build event and reference the outputs of several assemblies built by other dependent projects. In WiX projects, I can use macros from other referenced projects in the solution to get information like so

```
$(var.OtherProject.TargetPath)
```

However, when I try to use the above line in a pre or post build task for a C# project, I get the following error when building:

```
The expression """.OtherProject" cannot be evaluated. Method 'System.String.OtherProject' not found.
```

How do I reference the outputs of other dependent projects in my solution?